# Limit of $n^{A\lg n}\cdot 2^{n-n^A}$ for $A > 1$

Tags: limits, logarithms

Can anybody think of a straightforward way to see that this limit equals $0$ for all $A > 1$? I can only think of applying L'Hopital's rule, which leads to a godawful mess. Perhaps there's a useful upper bound for $n^{\lg n}$?

Comment: Limit... as what?  $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Is $\lg$ supposed to be the base 2 log?  Or did you mean to use $\ln$, the natural log?

Comment: Maybe use $n^{Alog(n)} = (2^{log(n)})^{A log(n)}$ (I'm assuming the log is in base 2, but this is applicable for any base).

Comment: Yes, as n approaches infinity. And yes, I do mean the base 2 log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n^{A\lg n}=2^{A\ln^2n}$$

Thus, we may rewrite it as

$$2^{A\lg^2n+n-n^A}$$

As $n\to\infty$ the $-n^A$ dominates, since $A\lg^2n=\mathcal O(n)$ and $n^A>n^1$.  Thus, as $n\to\infty$, the limit is simply $0$.